# Not able to connect to REST API inside a service in some devices

Tags: android, service, retrofit

I am using retrofit 1.9 in order to create and use connections with server , its working perfectly in app , but when i am trying to hit api in a service , it is returning me this error

"retrofit.RetrofitError: unexpected end of stream on Connection{, proxy=DIRECT@ cipherSuite=none protocol=http/1.1} (recycle count=0)"
and only in some devices like for instance in my Xiaomi Redmi note 3.

Here is my code:-

```
    public class TrackingService extends Service implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {
private String latitude = "", longitude = "";
private PrefsManager mPrefs;
int requestID = 42;
private int time = 120000;
private static final long SERVICE_INTERVAL = 60000;
private static final long SERVICE_FASTEST = 30000;
private static final long ONE_MIN = 1000;
private GoogleApiClient googleApiClient;
private FusedLocationProviderApi fusedLocationProviderApi = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi;
private boolean canGetLocation = false;
private LocationRequest locationRequest;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private final String TAG = "MyAwesomeApp";
private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        updateLocation();
    }
};
private Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        getHandler1().postDelayed(runnable, time);
        return true;
    }
});
private Handler handler1 = new Handler();

public Handler getHandler1() {
    return handler1;
}

private NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        canGetLocation = !(!locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) && !locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER));
    }
};
private BroadcastReceiver receiverNetwork = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        getHandler1().removeCallbacks(runnable);
        time = 5000;
        handler.sendMessage(new Message());
    }
};
private static API REST_CLIENT;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    registerReceiver(receiverNetwork, new IntentFilter(Constants.NETWORK_BROADCAST));
    registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(Constants.INTENT_LOCATION_SERVICE));
}

private void init() {
    mPrefs = new PrefsManager(this);
    locationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
    locationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
    locationRequest.setInterval(SERVICE_INTERVAL);
    locationRequest.setFastestInterval(SERVICE_FASTEST);
    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    canGetLocation = !(!locationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) && !locationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER));
    googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).build();
    try {
        googleApiClient.connect();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    updateLocation();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.e(TAG, "GPSTrackerNew destroyed!");
    googleApiClient.disconnect();
    try {
        unregisterReceiver(receiverNetwork);
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    this.stopForeground(true);
    super.onDestroy();
}

/**
 * Update driver location for live tracking
 */
private void updateLocation() {
    if (canGetLocation()) {
        /*setNotification(this, getResources().getString(R.string.tracking));*/
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(latitude) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(longitude)) {
            get().updateLocation(mPrefs.getAccessToken(), latitude, longitude,
                    new Callback<PojoBase>() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(PojoBase pojoBase, Response response) {
                            try {
                                if (pojoBase.status == Constants.SUCCESS) {
                                    time = 120000;
                                    handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                                    getHandler1().removeCallbacks(runnable);
                                    handler.sendMessage(new Message());
                                    setNotification(TrackingService.this, getResources().getString(R.string.tracking));
                                } else if (pojoBase.status == Constants.LOGIN_EXPIRED) {
                                    onDestroy();
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                onDestroy();
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                            time = 5000;
                            setNotification(TrackingService.this, getResources().getString(R.string.network_error));
                            handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
                            getHandler1().removeCallbacks(runnable);
                            handler.sendMessage(new Message());
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            time = 5000;
            handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
            getHandler1().removeCallbacks(runnable);
            handler.sendMessage(new Message());
        }
    } else {
        time = 5000;
        handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
        getHandler1().removeCallbacks(runnable);
        handler.sendMessage(new Message());
        setNotification(this, getResources().getString(R.string.not_able_to_fetch_location));
    }
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    init();
    return START_STICKY;
}

private void setNotification(Context context, String message) {
    Intent intent = null;
    intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, requestID,
            intent, 0);
    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    this.startForeground(requestID, mBuilder.build());
}

@Override
public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
    fusedLocationProviderApi.requestLocationUpdates(googleApiClient,
            locationRequest, this);
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has been suspend");
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location != null) {
        Log.i("From service:", "Location received: " + location.toString());
        canGetLocation = true;
        latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
        longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());
    } else {
        canGetLocation = false;
    }


}

public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return canGetLocation;
}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection has been failed");
}

public static API get() {
    if (REST_CLIENT == null) {
        RestAdapter.Builder adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                .setClient(new OkClient(getClient()));
        adapter.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.BASIC);
        adapter.setEndpoint(Constants.ROOT);
        RestAdapter mAdapter = adapter.build();
        REST_CLIENT = mAdapter.create(API.class);
    }
    return REST_CLIENT;
}

private static OkHttpClient getClient() {
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    client.setConnectTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    return client;
}
```

}

Can anyone tell why is this happening ?

TIA

Comment: its server side error, server returns response that is not parsed by restrofit. Try to verify in log, update your log level to .BODY from .BASIC. And look into response what's going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Try to use execute instead enqueue call.Services is already on different thread. So if you are making a network call on different thread you should run api on same thread.